# Title of a comic read in late 80s featuring an ant-like insect alien race with wasp-like spaceships

Tags: story-identification, comics

I am looking for a comic, which I owned some 20 years ago, in the late 80s. Sadly I remember very little about it, but you might put together these small puzzles and help me find out what was the title.

What I remember: It was a sci-fi title, there were space battles in it and there was some sort of alien insect like race which had giant spaceships closely resembling wasps. These wasp spaceships had red superstructure and their abdomen was transparent green as, far as I remember.

Also, the alien soldiers came out bursting from the ground almost every time (they were ant-like beings, as far as I remember).

I suspect that the comic was on either German or French - I could not read any of these languages that time so I can't tell now which one.
I have been searching for this title for almost two decades without luck.

Comment: You've got quite a few details, but take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @zab please don’t make pointless edits. Changing numerical to the spelled out version isn’t a necessary or needed edit.

Answer (score 3):

I've never beer a comic reader but I used to be an avid RPG player.
And I definitely remember an AD&D setting I fell in love for: **Spelljammer**.
That is, D&D in space.

The details you give fit the setting's main evil guys, the Neogi, who resemble tattooed insects: spiders mostly but they could also be ants with an eel's head. And they employ mindless Umber Hulks for their brute force, which look like huge beetles.
This is what the Neogi look like:

[image]

Ships in Spelljammer have peculiar shapes (insect-like, usually), each linked mostly to a single race: the Neogi travel in the Deathspider, that despite the name might resemble a red-bellied wasp.
[image]

Lastly, in the late Eighties/early Nineties they also published a [**Spelljammer comic series**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelljammer_(comics)) in which the Neogi would make more than an appearance, given their relevance in the setting.
So chances are this is the comic you remember.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Zab, I know and love Spelljammer, even played it a few times. I remember the MindFlayer Nautiloids and that even Halfings had a funny ship, drawn by swans. Sadly, I am sure that the comic was sci-fi and not set in Spelljammer, but thanks to the effort, I really appriciate it.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly Spelljammer is what came to my mind at once while reading your description: I have no other clue as to what the comic you're looking for might be. Good luck on your search! And yes, Spelljammer was...crazy. Andf fun!

Answer (score 0):

Is it the comic Yoko Tsuno, The Titans?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the comic the OP was looking for, specifying any plot points that match the description given in the question, and any that don't. It'd help other users decide how likely this answer is to be correct or not. Specifying the year in which this was published would be helpful too.

Comment: Currently leafing through the album, but I don't think that can be it - no space battles (the story is set on a planets surface), the alien mothership (there is only one) does not resemble a wasp, and the insectoid aliens rather resemble grasshoppers.